# Método POST en rutas de laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ajax

A la hora de enviar por POST con Ajax un formulario, me dice el siguiente mensaje

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

El formulario tiene su **@csrf**, y la ruta veo que está listada cuando hago un **route:list**

```
Route::post('customer/ajaxRequestPost', [CustomerController::class, 'ajaxRequestPost'])->name('customer.ajaxRequestPost')->middleware('auth');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi elemento `<form>`

```
<form action="http://localhost/customer/ajaxRequestPost" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="createCustomerAjax">
....
```

Y aquí el código **js** con **ajax**

```
  $("#createCustomerAjax").submit(function (e) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $("#createCustomerAjax").serialize();
    var type = "POST";
    var ajaxurl = "{{ route('customer.ajaxRequestPost') }}";
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
    });
   });

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Mi método **ajaxRequestPost**

```
public function ajaxRequestPost(Request $request) {
  $ret = [
    "prueba" => "1"
  ];
        
  return json_encode($ret);
}
```

Comment: tienes mas rutas con el mismo nombre o el mismo path?

Comment: ¿En la variable `ajaxurl` no tienes un `.` donde debiera ir una `/`?

Comment: El method de tu `form` esta escrito como `POST` ?

Comment: Puedes mostrar el método: ```ajaxRequestPost``` y tu formulaio también?

Comment: Recuerda tambien colocar en las etiquetas <form method="POST> porque a pesar de que estas usando AJAX, estas usando el evento submit

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con más información

Comment: Estás ejecutando dos request desde el mismo formulario? Una mediante el atributo `action` y otra mediante JavaScript `AJAX`? Tu ruta `/customer` y tu ruta `/customer/ajaxRequestPost`.

Comment: porque ejecutas tu action usando la ruta absoluta? '-action="http://localhost/customer/ajaxRequestPost"-'  si tu archivo de Routes contiene esta ruta seria suficiente con mandarle '/customer/ajaxRequestPost/' y en tu ajaxurl deberia de ser {{ url( . . . ) }} no?

Comment: Ejecuta `php artisan route:list` y muestranos lo que sale. Tambien `php route:clear`

Comment: ¿Has hecho un `console.log(ajaxurl)` ? Para ver que dirección esta enviándote.